# Convert hex value in C#

Tags: c#, hex

I am trying to display a two digit hex value into 16bit hex value. i.e
value =81 into 0x0000000000000081 . I have done the following code  :

```
public long GetHexNumber(long d)
    {

        return long.Parse(d.ToString("X"), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    }
```

but the above code returns the same hex value i.e 81 . Kindly help

Comment: What are you expecting? You are immediatly reparsing the hex value.

Comment: The hex value is going to be the same all the time. If you want to get it as string , `ToString("X")` would do

Comment: 0x0000000000000081  is 64 bits not 16 bits btw.

Comment: I think the problem is only in your mind. What do you need this for? I guess your mixing _value_ and _representation_. `0x81` is `129` is `0b10000001`. It's the same value. The only thing you can change is how it is represented as string or how the debugger shows it. But for the bits in your `long` variable it's always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Int64.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fd69cbc(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
    public string GetHexNumber(long d)
    {
        return d.ToString("X16");
    }
```

X ... for converting to hexString

16... for converting it to 16 digit string

If you want it to have a leading "0x" change it to:

```
    return "0x" + d.ToString("X16");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by providing a good test example, we want

1. Having an integer (e.g. `81`)
2. Treat is as if it's not *decimal*, but *hexadecimal*: `0x81` (we mechanically add `0x`)
3. Obtain its value (`0x81 == 129`)

Something like this:

```
 Value -> 0xValue
```

If it's your case, the solution can be

```
 // static: we don't have any need in "this" instance
 public static long GetHexNumber(long value) {
   return Convert.ToInt64(value.ToString(), 16);
 }
```

Test

```
 long test = 81;

 Console.WriteLine(81);
 // C# 6.0+ string interpolating
 // if don't use C# 6.0, put it as formatting: 
 // Console.WriteLine("{0:X16}", GetHexNumber(test)); 
 Console.WriteLine($"{GetHexNumber(test):X16}");
```